# when I initiate second button click -> AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'readfile'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid() #put it on the grid
        self.create_widgets()
    #widget
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button1 = Button(self)
        self.button1.grid(row = 3, column = 5, columnspan = 2, stick = E)
        self.button1["text"] = "Browse"
        self.button1["command"] = self.update_count
        self.pack()
#here
        self.text1 = Text(self)
        self.text1 = Text(self, width = 41, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
        self.text1.grid(row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 2, stick = W)
# here
        self.button2 = Button(self)
        self.button2.grid(row = 5, column = 5, columnspan = 2, stick = E)
        self.pack()
        self.button2["text"] = "OK"
        self.button2["command"] = self.readfile

       # select list box
        self.listbox1 = Listbox(self, selectmode = EXTENDED)
        self.listbox1 = Listbox(self, width = 51, height = 5)
        self.listbox1.grid(row = 5, column = 1, columnspan = 2, stick = W)

        self.label1 = Label(self)
        self.label1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
        self.label1["text"] = "Choose the data log file folder ..."

        self.label2 = Label(self)
        self.label2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
        self.label2["text"] = "Choose the data log file ..."

    #on click
    def update_count(self):

        path_string = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()     
        self.text1.delete(0.0, END)
        self.text1.insert(0.0, path_string)
    # read files
        onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(path_string) if isfile(join(path_string,f)) ]
        with open("output.txt", "w") as a:
            for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path_string):
               for filename in files:
                     ffnames = os.path.join(filename)
                     self.listbox1.insert(END, ffnames)
                     a.write(str(ffnames) + os.linesep)
        #on click
        def readfile(self):
            global listEx
            items = map(int, listbox1.curselection())
            result = listEx[items[0]]
            print result
    # main loop

    root = Tk() 
    root.title("Test Window")
    root.geometry("900x700")

    app = Application(root)

    root.mainloop() #main loop
```

Thanks in advance,

Can anyone help me to fix this error, I have got two button, first button works, now I need to read a file name from the listbox so have declared a constructor to do the work, eventually I got an AttributeError, don't know why?

I am new to Python, as a beginner struggling to fix, please help me.

Ramas

Comment: Is the indentation for `readfile()` off in your program? It looks like it's under the `update_count()` method here.

Comment: Can you include some more information about the error in your post?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly the problem -- your class has no method named `readfile`. It looks like you have indented the method incorrectly, causing it to be private to the `update_count` method. The solution is to remove one level of indentation to the function definition, so that it is in the proper scope.